# how to use Enclose.js

Tags: node.js, compilation

How would I compile this use Enclose.js?
I  have tried and got this error

x file "was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script."

I then tried to add a config file as the docks say to do but have gotten nowhere with that and now I do not know what to do so I have come hear to see if someone can help.

```
var fs = require('./graceful-fs');
saveToFile();

function saveToFile() {

    var date = new Date();

    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/Output.txt", date + "\r\n");

} //save dater to file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove `__dirname` and use `./` in it's place.

```
var fs = require('./graceful-fs');
saveToFile();

function saveToFile() {

    var date = new Date();

    fs.writeFileSync("./Output.txt", date + "\r\n");

} //save dater to file
```